# ALexa Skill C# Queue multiple Audio Files

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

we currently try to play multiple audio files from an Alexa Skill at a certain intent. We sadly only are able to play one audio file. Our code for that is the following

```
 response.Response.Directives.Add(new AudioPlayerPlayDirective()
 {

      PlayBehavior = PlayBehavior.Enqueue,
      AudioItem = new Alexa.NET.Response.Directive.AudioItem()
      {
         Stream = new AudioItemStream()
            {
              Url = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/morseitech/360ms.mp3",
              Token = "360ms",
              ExpectedPreviousToken = "120ms"
            }
       }
  });
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: How do I add a second audio file?

Answer (score 0):

You enqueue your next URL in PlaybackNearlyFinished handler.
Check out this doc:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playbacknearlyfinished
As well as playlist progression:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playlist-progression